# reactJS remove Items from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I fetch a list of users from aws cognitio, that works perfectly.

Now I want to iterate over this array and remove those which don't match to a Client ID, that does not work properly.

what is my failure in this case?

My code looks like this:

```
this.awsSDKAuth().listUsers(params, (err, data) => {
    if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
    else {
        let userArray = data.Users.slice(0);

        console.log(userArray);
        userArray.forEach((user,index) => {
            user.Attributes.forEach(attr =>  {
                if(attr.Name === "custom:client" && attr.Value !== clientId){
                        userArray.splice(index,1);
                    console.log(userArray);
                }
            }
        )});
        console.log(userArray);
        this.setState({
            users: userArray
        })
    }
});
```

Thanks

In this case I got two useres one with clientID = 36
and one with clientID = 35.

only the one with 36 should be displayed

[image]

Question: Should I do this recoursive? Breac the foreach when one is found and start again? maybe of wrong indexing?

Comment: your if else statement looks like it has a weird syntax. If { } else { }. If that's fine for you then probably should show us what is the error message?

Comment: that weired if else comes from aws ;) just copy paste, but you're right I'll fix it.

Problem is that not all users that matches the second if are removed

Comment: What does each user object look like ?

Comment: added some more info above

Comment: @Felix...if you change your existing code with attr.Value !== clientId to attr.Value === clientId. Does your code works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> what is my failure in this case?

You are mutating array while iterating over it. Use `filter` instead.

```
this.awsSDKAuth().listUsers(params, (err, data) => {
    if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
    else {
        let userArray = data.Users.slice(0)
           .filter(user => user.Attributes.some(attr => attr.Name === "custom:client" && attr.Value === clientId));

        this.setState({
            users: userArray
        })
    }
});
```

```js
const userData = [{
    Attributes: [{
        name: 'custom:client',
        value: '36'
      },
      {
        name: 'FirstName',
        value: 'Keep'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    Attributes: [{
        name: 'custom:client',
        value: '35'
      },
      {
        name: 'FirstName',
        value: 'Omit'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    Attributes: [{
        name: 'custom:client',
        value: '36'
      },
      {
        name: 'FirstName',
        value: 'Keep'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    Attributes: [{
        name: 'custom:client',
        value: '37'
      },
      {
        name: 'FirstName',
        value: 'Omit'
      }
    ]
  }
]

console.log(
  userData.filter(user => user.Attributes.some(attr => (attr.name === 'custom:client' && attr.value === '36')))
)
```

Comment: does not work as I thought about, I get the one with ide 36 and lots of others with 35

Comment: shouldn't the condition be attr.Value === clientId

Comment: @Felix Right you need `attr.Value === clientId`

Comment: @YuryTarabanko.... I want to understand how array mutates if we use foreach over it. Could you explain a little bit?

Comment: @MukulSharma It is not `forEach` but `splice` mutates array in place. When you remove an item all indices shift.

Answer (score 0):

This might do it for you. You can filter the users based on the criteria that the user returns an attribute that has the correct name and value.

```
this.awsSDKAuth().listUsers(params, (err, data) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  } else {
    this.setState({
      users: data.Users.filter(user => user.Attributes.some(attr => attr.Name === "custom:client" && attr.Value === clientID)),
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: looks nice but now I got more wrong users in the array... lots of the users with client ID 35 ... only want those with 36

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: does not work. clientID is an string (comes from aws) and I want to use clientID as a var.